# How to save DWG to BIM 360 Docs after cloud processing

Tags: python, autodesk-forge, autocad, autodesk-designautomation

I'm writing a design automation program that reads files from a BIM 360 Docs project, runs a lisp routine on them, and saves them back to the same project. The program can access the files and run routines, but fails to save them back to the project. At the moment, I'm using the same url for the output that I am for the imput, which I'm sure is whats causing problems. However, I don't know what url I should be using for the output. It also could be the command line I'm using for accoreconsole, but I think the former is more likely. Anyone have any ideas?

Command Line:

```
["$(engine.path)\\accoreconsole.exe /i $(args[inputFile].path) /al $(appbundles[" + bundleName + "].path) /s $(settings[script].path)"]
```

Parameters:

```
{"inputFile":{"ondemand":False,"required":True,"verb":"get","zip":False,"description":zipname,"localName":"$(inputFile)"},"outputFile":{"ondemand":False,"required":True,"zip":False,"verb":"put","description":zipname,"localName":"outputFile.dwg"}}
```

Input url example:

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/234790a4-d279-4839-b00b-6f3aab9297bb.dwg

Workitem arguments:

```
{"inputFile":{"url":url,"headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer " + token}},"outputFile":{"verb":"put","url":output_url,"headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer " + token}}}
```

Log:

```
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Starting work item d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Start download phase.
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Start preparing AppPackage 41205.
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Start download phase.
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Download bits and install app to local cache.
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Start downloading file https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/234790a4-d279-4839-b00b-6f3aab9297bb.dwg.
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] End downloading file https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/234790a4-d279-4839-b00b-6f3aab9297bb.dwg. 38839 bytes have been written to T:\Aces\Jobs\d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4\234790a4-d279-4839-b00b-6f3aab9297bb.dwg.
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] End download phase.
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Command line: [ /i T:\Aces\Jobs\d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4\234790a4-d279-4839-b00b-6f3aab9297bb.dwg /al T:\Aces\Applications\3110fac452e9ee4c4d8c00a56aceef4f.gufcCWA4iPj1YRork8Qhgf75TnysvKiu.41205[1].package /s T:\Aces\Jobs\d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4\setting_514.scr]
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Start script phase.
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] ### Command line arguments: /isolate HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4 "T:\Aces\Jobs\d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4\userdata" /exe "T:\Aces\AcesRoot\23.0\coreEngine\Exe\accoreconsole.exe"  /i T:\Aces\Jobs\d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4\234790a4-d279-4839-b00b-6f3aab9297bb.dwg /al T:\Aces\Applications\3110fac452e9ee4c4d8c00a56aceef4f.gufcCWA4iPj1YRork8Qhgf75TnysvKiu.41205[1].package /s T:\Aces\Jobs\d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4\setting_514.scr.
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Start AutoCAD Core Engine standard output dump.
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Redirect stdout (file: T:\Aces\Jobs\d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4\tmp\accc6882).
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Sandboxer: StdOutConsoleMode: processed-output: disabled,auto
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Isolating to regKey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4, userDataFolder=T:\Aces\Jobs\d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4\userdata.
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Launching sandbox process: [T:\Aces\AcesRoot\23.0\coreEngine\Exe\accoreconsole.exe /i T:\Aces\Jobs\d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4\234790a4-d279-4839-b00b-6f3aab9297bb.dwg /al T:\Aces\Applications\3110fac452e9ee4c4d8c00a56aceef4f.gufcCWA4iPj1YRork8Qhgf75TnysvKiu.41205[1].package /s T:\Aces\Jobs\d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4\setting_514.scr  /isolate HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4 T:\Aces\Jobs\d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4\userdata]
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Waiting for child process to complete: 216
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Redirect stdout (file: T:\Aces\Jobs\d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4\tmp\accc37042).
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] AcCoreConsole: StdOutConsoleMode: processed-output: disabled,auto
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] AutoCAD Core Engine Console - Copyright 2018 Autodesk, Inc.  All rights reserved. (P.45.Z.52)
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Execution Path:
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] T:\Aces\AcesRoot\23.0\coreEngine\Exe\accoreconsole.exe
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Isolating to regkey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4, userDataFolder=T:\Aces\Jobs\d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4\userdata.
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Version Number: P.45.Z.52 (UNICODE)
[04/12/2019 20:51:12] Current Directory: T:\Aces\Jobs\d5bfa4f107684a69a39e6c0c00380de4
[04/12/2019 20:51:13] Regenerating model.
[04/12/2019 20:51:13] Command:
[04/12/2019 20:51:13] Command: Enter BACKSPACE to interrupt script.
[04/12/2019 20:51:13] Command:
[04/12/2019 20:51:13] Process exit code: 0
[04/12/2019 20:51:13] End AutoCAD Core Engine standard output dump.
[04/12/2019 20:51:13] End script phase.
[04/12/2019 20:51:13] Start upload phase.
[04/12/2019 20:51:13] Error: Non-optional output [outputFile.dwg] is missing .
[04/12/2019 20:51:13] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase Publishing of job.
[04/12/2019 20:51:13] Job finished with result FailedMissingOutput
[04/12/2019 20:51:13] Job Status:
{
  "status": "failedInstructions",
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any commands in AutoCAD command line echo after its launch. Can you check whether your "settings/script" section (of you activity) contains any AutoCAD command(s)? Or whether each command is followed by a new-line?

Comment: My settings/script section is pointing to a lisp routine in the app bundle.

Comment: Hi Ryan, Can you ping me at qun.lu@autodesk.com so we can look more closely on your activity and app related to this workitem? Thanks, - Qun

Comment: Ryan, in your activity "settings", change to: "settings": { "script": { "value": "accore\n" } }. You need a line-break after "accore" command to enter the command.

Comment: Hi Qun, I added the line break and I'm still getting the same error from before, except now I'm getting an error saying "Unknown command "ACCORE"." Do you think the issue could be with the xml file I'm creating in my app bundle?